# Optimization as LP on the convex hull of its solution space

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, convex-optimization

I have heard claims that for a certain class of optimization problems, one can re-write the problem as a linear-programming problem on the convex hull of the solution space of the original problem (even though enumerating the constraints that define the polytope could be computationally *very* expensive).

Is this correct? If so, what class of optimization problems can be re-written this way? and what references can I use to back up this claim?

Comment: Depending on how you define your optimization problem, any optimization problem that can be solved in polynomial time can be solved via linear programming, since the Linear Programming problem is P-complete. (However, even approximating a good solution to a given linear program remains P-complete.)